# Failed to Execute Build Analyzer Maven Plugin in Local SDK

Tags: aem

```
[INFO] --- aemanalyser-maven-plugin:0.9.2:analyse (default-analyse) @ aem-guides-myproject.analyse ---
[INFO] Starting analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author.prod:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions analyser task that checks that listed packages are actually exported [api-regions]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions check order analyser task [api-regions-check-order]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Import/Export Check [api-regions-exportsimports]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions cross-feature duplicate export task [api-regions-crossfeature-dups]...
[INFO] - Executing Configuration API analyser task [configuration-api]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Natice Code Check [bundle-nativecode]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Initial Content Check [bundle-content]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Resources Check [bundle-resources]...
[INFO] - Executing Requirements Capabilities check [requirements-capabilities]...
[INFO] Analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author.prod:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' finished : 0 warnings, 3 errors.
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~asyncjssightly.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern : Property is not allowed
[ERROR] Analyser detected errors on feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author.prod:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'. See log output for error messages.
[INFO] Starting analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish.prod:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions analyser task that checks that listed packages are actually exported [api-regions]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions check order analyser task [api-regions-check-order]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Import/Export Check [api-regions-exportsimports]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions cross-feature duplicate export task [api-regions-crossfeature-dups]...
[INFO] - Executing Configuration API analyser task [configuration-api]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Natice Code Check [bundle-nativecode]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Initial Content Check [bundle-content]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Resources Check [bundle-resources]...
[INFO] - Executing Requirements Capabilities check [requirements-capabilities]...
[INFO] Analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish.prod:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' finished : 0 warnings, 3 errors.
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~asyncjssightly.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern : Property is not allowed
[ERROR] Analyser detected errors on feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish.prod:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'. See log output for error messages.
[INFO] Starting analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish.stage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions analyser task that checks that listed packages are actually exported [api-regions]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions check order analyser task [api-regions-check-order]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Import/Export Check [api-regions-exportsimports]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions cross-feature duplicate export task [api-regions-crossfeature-dups]...
[INFO] - Executing Configuration API analyser task [configuration-api]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Natice Code Check [bundle-nativecode]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Initial Content Check [bundle-content]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Resources Check [bundle-resources]...
[INFO] - Executing Requirements Capabilities check [requirements-capabilities]...
[INFO] Analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish.stage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' finished : 0 warnings, 2 errors.
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~asyncjssightly.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern : Property is not allowed
[ERROR] Analyser detected errors on feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish.stage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'. See log output for error messages.
[INFO] Starting analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions analyser task that checks that listed packages are actually exported [api-regions]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions check order analyser task [api-regions-check-order]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Import/Export Check [api-regions-exportsimports]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions cross-feature duplicate export task [api-regions-crossfeature-dups]...
[INFO] - Executing Configuration API analyser task [configuration-api]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Natice Code Check [bundle-nativecode]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Initial Content Check [bundle-content]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Resources Check [bundle-resources]...
[INFO] - Executing Requirements Capabilities check [requirements-capabilities]...
[INFO] Analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' finished : 0 warnings, 2 errors.
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~asyncjssightly.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern : Property is not allowed
[ERROR] Analyser detected errors on feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-publish:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'. See log output for error messages.
[INFO] Starting analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions analyser task that checks that listed packages are actually exported [api-regions]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions check order analyser task [api-regions-check-order]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Import/Export Check [api-regions-exportsimports]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions cross-feature duplicate export task [api-regions-crossfeature-dups]...
[INFO] - Executing Configuration API analyser task [configuration-api]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Natice Code Check [bundle-nativecode]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Initial Content Check [bundle-content]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Resources Check [bundle-resources]...
[INFO] - Executing Requirements Capabilities check [requirements-capabilities]...
[INFO] Analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' finished : 0 warnings, 2 errors.
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~asyncjssightly.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern : Property is not allowed
[ERROR] Analyser detected errors on feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'. See log output for error messages.
[INFO] Starting analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author.stage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions analyser task that checks that listed packages are actually exported [api-regions]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions check order analyser task [api-regions-check-order]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Import/Export Check [api-regions-exportsimports]...
[INFO] - Executing Api Regions cross-feature duplicate export task [api-regions-crossfeature-dups]...
[INFO] - Executing Configuration API analyser task [configuration-api]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Natice Code Check [bundle-nativecode]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Initial Content Check [bundle-content]...
[INFO] - Executing Bundle Resources Check [bundle-resources]...
[INFO] - Executing Requirements Capabilities check [requirements-capabilities]...
[INFO] Analyzing feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author.stage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' finished : 0 warnings, 2 errors.
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~asyncjssightly.org.apache.sling.commons.log.level : Value error does not match provided options
[ERROR] Configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~myproject.org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern : Property is not allowed
[ERROR] Analyser detected errors on feature 'com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject:aem-guides-myproject.analyse:slingosgifeature:aggregated-author.stage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'. See log output for error messages.
```

ERROR is :

Failed to execute goal com.adobe.aem:aemanalyser-maven-plugin:0.9.2:analyse (default-analyse) on project aem-guides-myproject.analyse: One or more feature analyser(s) detected feature error(s), please read the plugin log for more details -> [Help 1]

I am using following command to create AEM project

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=26 -DappTitle="My Citi Sites Project" -DappId="myproject" -DgroupId="com.adobe.aem.guides.myproject" -DartifactId="aem-guides-myproject" -Dversion="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" -DaemVersion="cloud"
```

Project is created sucessfully but the problem is while building project using  `mvn clean install -PautoInstallSinglePackage` getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

If you used the AEM Project Archetype to setup your project, make sure to adjust the property in the root Maven pom.xml like below.

I have changed property in root pom.xml, I have updated version of AEM Analyser to latest version.

Old version: [pom.xml]

```
<properties>
    <aemanalyser.version>0.9.2</aemanalyser.version>
</properties>

 <build>
        <plugins> </plugins>
           <pluginManagement>
                <!-- AEM Analyser Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aemanalyser-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${aemanalyser.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Latest Version: [pom.xml]

```
<properties>
    <aemanalyser.version>1.3.0</aemanalyser.version> <!-- Make sure to use the latest release -->
</properties>

 <build>
        <plugins> </plugins>
           <pluginManagement>
                <!-- AEM Analyser Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aemanalyser-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${aemanalyser.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Check latest version of AEM Analyser Maven Plugin https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.adobe.aem/aemanalyser-maven-plugin